# Game Kit Send data to offline player

Tags: ios, gamekit, game-center

I am pretty sure i know the answer but is it possible to send data using game kit to a player who is not playing the game anymore so next time he loads the game the data will be there. Is there any sort of messaging queue in gamecenter that can hold data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, this is not possible if you let Game Center host the game. But you can set up your own server which stores the data and hands it over to the client while still having Game Centers match making functionality.